# Pointer to an array of characters

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, copy, structure

I'm trying to take an integer input from user and whichever the value is. I want it to access the same value in the array structure.

for example this code is for a number of PCs and im trying to acess one of them.

This is a demo code which the last two lines are wrong but i hope u get the idea.

```
struct user
{
    int pc_no[20];

};

void(main){

printf("enter which pc you would like to access and do operations on. \n");

int choice;

scanf("%d",choice);

struct user pc;
strcpy(choice,pc_no);

printf("%d",pc_no[choice]);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is more wrong than just the last two lines. You are not including any headers. Your definition of `main` is wrong. Parameter passed to `scanf` is wrong. At the end of `main` a `}` is missing. Your compiler should already tell you about most of these severe errors.

Comment: What is `pc_no` supposed to be? There is no variable with that name. You have a field within variable `pc` though. That means you must use `pc.pc_no`. But feeding this into `strcpy` without initialization is wrong. Also using `choice` in `strcpy` is wrong. It is not an address of a buffer that could hold a string.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings. For GCC or Clang use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. Read, understand and fix all of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fast wrote this code as a demonstration of my question.  all I'm trying to do is a system containing a number of PCs and access each of them separately to do other operations on them afterward.

Comment: Please tell us in you own words what `strcpy(choice,pc_no);` supposed to do? Hint: it doesn't make any sense whatsoever. Other hint: there is no array of chars in the code you show

Comment: Please don't "fast write" some code that is full of bugs. How would we know which of these bugs is your real issue? Instead provide some real code that is your current effort to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are wanting to know how you might update specific array entries in your structure.  Following is a snippet of code you might evaluate to get a feel for how date elements might be updated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 20

struct user
{
    int pc_no[SIZE];
};

int main()
{
    struct user pc;
    int select = 0;
    int value  = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        pc.pc_no[i] = 999;              /* Initialize the structure array */
    }

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter the PC you wish to update (0 - %d) or enter -1 to quit: ", SIZE - 1);
        scanf("%d", &select);

        if (select < 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (select >= SIZE)
        {
            printf("Please enter a value from '0' to '%d'\n", SIZE - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Enter the value to be stored: ");
            scanf("%d", &value);
            pc.pc_no[select] = value;   /* Store the value in the selected array position */
        }

    }

    printf("PC Value\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", pc.pc_no[i]);    /* List out the value */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Following is the output from the selection and entry of some of the array values within the "pc" structure.

```
Enter the PC you wish to update (0 - 19) or enter -1 to quit: -1
PC Value
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
33
999
999
50988
453
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
```

Give that a try to see if that enlightens you.